# Counting cells that contain =

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to count cells that contain the = sign. I have done this many times before but for some reason this time it is counting the blanks and none of the = signs.

The formula used is `=COUNTIF($BR2:$CU2,"=")`

Any ideas why it may not be working?

[image]

Comment: How about `=COUNTIF($BR2:$CU2,"==")`?

Comment: As @TwistyImpersonator implies, when you use `"="` it is taken as a relational operator, rather than a value, so your formula counts blank cells. Another alternative is `"^=$"`, which defines the value sought as a regular expression and avoids having the relational operator at the start of the string. @TwistyImpersonator should expand his comment as an answer, as it is a puzzling problem until it is understood.

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula simply needs an additional `=`:

```
=COUNTIF($BR2:$CU2,"==")
```

COUNTIF's second argument specifies the criterion cells must match to be counted. The criterion must begin with a relational operator, such as `=` to indicate cells must match the specified value exactly, or `>` when cells must be greater than the value specified after the operator.

If you wanted to count cells that contained the letter `A`, the criterion would be:

```
"=A"
```

Which is translated: "cells must be exactly equal to `A`".

In your case you want cells "that are exactly equal to `=`", so the criterion is:

```
"=="
```

The first equal sign tells Excel the cells "must exactly contain the following", and the second equal sign tells Excel the specific value (character) you're testing for.